# Why can't I associate my meta account?

Tags: support, user-accounts, meta, linked-accounts

Now that I understand that I need an OpenID (other than the default Google/Gmail OpenID!) to associate accounts between StackExchange sites, I'm trying to associate all my accounts. That works fine, except for [this very meta account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147540/michel-de-ruiter). The `accounts` tab does show the accounts of other sites, but if I press "Associate With ...", I get:

> user Id 357313 already associated with
>   another account

What's up with my account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually means you have multiple, duplicate accounts on one or more websites.

1. Go to Stack Overflow
2. Go to your user page
3. Go to the accounts tab
4. Click "Clear Associations"
5. Re-associate with each site