# How do I link meta.stackoverflow to SO?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I associate my meta account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54407/why-cant-i-associate-my-meta-account)
>   [Shouldn't my Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow reputations be the same?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66939/shouldnt-my-meta-stack-overflow-and-stack-overflow-reputations-be-the-same)

I have read through some of the previous questions about linking SO to Meta and can't find a definitive answer or it's been months since it was last brought up (so I apologize in advance for asking a repetitive question). Is there any way I can link these two accounts and have reputation points carry over? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What's your SO account? I can't find one with the same name or login.

Comment: Potentially a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66939/shouldnt-my-meta-stack-overflow-and-stack-overflow-reputations-be-the-same, or possibly http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54407/why-cant-i-associate-my-meta-account depending on what the OP is trying to ask... or maybe neither of the above.

Comment: @Popular I think you're right

Comment: @michael I agree, I can't find this user anywhere on Stack Overflow with any possible valid search I can come up with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

This meta is special.

---

//Here I have assumed that you are asking about the situation where meta.foo.stackexchange.com reputation is inherited from foo.stackexchange.com.

If, instead you are asking about the 100 rep bonus for associating accounts, then you *can* get that. There is an "accounts" tab in you profile on every site, and you control associations from there.

Comment: Oh, it's sad that I just wrote that whole paragraph and completely missed what he was saying. Yeah, meta.SO reputation isn't connected to SO reputation like most SE metas are; meta.SO is treated as its own SE site

Comment: @Michael - your answer is still partially valid as the OP hasn't associated his SO and MSO accounts, so he won't get the 100 point bonus (assuming 200+ points on SO).

Comment: @Michael Mrozek Thank you. I hope this helps other new meta.SO users in the future. I will close out this question.

Comment: @SDGuy, wait, so who was right? You thanked Michael but marked dmckee's answer as accepted, so I remain confused.

Comment: @popular demand - aren't they both right?